# How to recover Chromium bookmarks after reinstall?

Tags: data-recovery, bookmarks, chromium

I've had Windows with Chromium installed. Say it was on disk (A). My hardware crashed so I bought a brand new PC with a new disk (B). I've installed Chromium and I'd like to know if there's a way to import my bookmarks from disk (A) to my freshly installed Chromium.

Comment: Just so you know, you should back up your bookmarks using Google Sync. Go to Prefs>Personal Stuff> and at the top of the page, there's an option to sync data. You'll be prompted to login to your Google Account. Then, all your bookmarks will be synced. No one can access them, if you're worried about that. And if you log into another computer and sync data with your Google account, all your bookmarks will appear on that computer. It's great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just copy over the `Bookmarks` file from the old [user data folder](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).

- Windows XP

  - Google Chrome: `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
  - Chromium: `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Chromium\User Data\Default`
- Windows 7 or Vista

  - Google Chrome: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
  - Chromium: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default`

Comment: And what about Linux?

Comment: @hakermania: The linked Chrome documentation page has locations for all other OSes.